# Store query result (SQL Server) in an array (Razor)

Tags: sql-server, database, razor

I am trying to store the results obtained from the following query into an array:

```
@{
    var SelectLastCP = "SELECT [ID] FROM Table1"
    var SelectData2 = db.QuerySingle(SelectLastCP);
    var tempstring = SelectData2.ID;
}
```

The result from the query looks like this:

```
ID
01
02
03
.
.
.
```

I need to store those numbers somehow so I can work with them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Database.Query` instead of `QuerySingle`, you will return a collection. You can work with them using that:

```
foreach(var item in SelectData2)
{
    <div>@item.ID</div>
}
```

If you want to project it into an array, you can use LINQ:

```
var myArrayOfIds = SelectData2.Select(s => s.ID).ToArray();
```

Comment: Both solutions didn't work, may be I'm doing something wrong. This is the error I get when I try your first solution (foreach...): _Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'_

Comment: I misread your code first time. I've updated my reply accordingly.

Comment: Mike that totally worked. Now I'm trying to apply the same into my original query (please see update), but it won't work there. Would you know what the issue is? Thanks.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Do you get errors? What code are you using?

Comment: Looks to me like the column in your result is called N. I can't see where a column named Pt_ID is included in the resultset.

Comment: Yes, I have also tried _N_ and got the same error _Invalid column name "N"_